# laravel controller cannot use currentRouteName() inside construce()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have named routes:
`admin.post.category`
`admin.post.tag`
`admin.post.theme`

routes\admin.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post', 'as' => 'post.'], function () {
    Route::resource('category', 'Admin\Post\TermsController');
    Route::resource('theme', 'Admin\Post\TermsController');
    Route::resource('tag', 'Admin\Post\TermsController');
});
```

Http\Controller\Admin\Post\TermsController

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;

    $route_name = Route::currentRouteName();
    $arr = explode('.', $route_name);
    echo "<pre>".print_r($arr[2], 1)."</pre>"; exit;

}
```

When I visit the page http://localhost/admin/post/category, it can show category. But when I run command

```
php artisan route:list
```

It shows

```
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined offset: 2
```

If I move the three lines from __construct() to index()

```
$route_name = Route::currentRouteName();
$arr = explode('.', $route_name);
echo "<pre>".print_r($arr[2], 1)."</pre>"; exit;
```

Then "php artisan route:list" runs well.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's throwing the error because you have some routes with names that contain only 1 dot. So when you access `$arr[2]` it's undefined and thus the error `Undefined offset: 2`. Looks like your shoving every route method into a single controller. When you try to run `php artisan route:list` it checks every route, thereby invoking the constructor, so it fails for routes with names with just 1 dot. Change your code to this and it should work.

```
$route_name = \Route::currentRouteName();
$arr = explode('.', $route_name);

if (isset($arr[2])) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r($arr[2], 1)."</pre>";
}

exit;
```

Comment: I used your solution. But it's not "some routes with names that contain only 1 dot", because if echo $route_name in __construct(), it shows nothing in php artisan route:list output. Only on browser is ok. Thank you.